# Java - char's in strings

Tags: java, string, chars

I have made a file called AESencrypt which encrypts characters. I am trying to make this work by getting the input of the passwordField and encrypting it.
This is what I have tried, though it failed:

```
   char[]passwordInput=passwordField.getPassword();
   String encryptedPassword = AESencrypt.encrypt(passwordInput);
```

The encrypt method is defined as follows:

```
public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception { 
   Key key = generateKey(); 
   Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO); 
   c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key); 
   byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes()); 
   String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal); 
   return encryptedValue;
  }
```

and this is what doesn't work:

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
   char[] passwordInput = passwordField.getPassword(); 
   String passwordEnc = AESencrypt.encrypt(passwordInput); 
  }
```

For some reason, the `passwordInput` in brackets on the last line is giving an error.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This question is lacking some informations: 1) What error 2) How is AESencrypt.encrypt() defined

Comment: Is it static method with argument char[] and return type String ? and it is imported by import and is it in classpath ?

Comment: I don't think it's a static method.  Yes it is imported by import.  I am unsure about the other questions.

Comment: What is `passwordField.getPassword()` ?

Comment: It is a password field.  It gets the password entered.

Comment: I don't have access to what the error was, buying net beans it had a red line under it.  Sorry I'm currently on my iPhone.

Comment: There are a bunch of questions here. The clearest way of answering them would probably be to expand your code to be a complete program, including the imports, with the failing code in it main method.

Comment: I'll do this tomorrow.  Can you get a char[] value in a string?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that AESencrypt.encrypt signature is `public static char[] encrypt(char[])`. Then you should do `String encryptedPassword = new String(AESencrypt.encrypt(passwordInput));` instead.
If not, please post the signature method.

Comment: The AESencrypt encrypting method is:

Comment: The AESencrypt encrypting method is: public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }  This is what encrypts it.

Comment: And this is what doesn't work: `code`private void loginButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        char[] passwordInput = passwordField.getPassword();
        String passwordEnc = AESencrypt.encrypt(passwordInput);  
    } `code`

Comment: It just doesn't recognise passwordInput as a input to encode.  Any suggestions on how you would implement the code so it gets the password from the passwordField and the encrypt it using AESencrypt.encrypt.

Comment: But the encrypt method first parameter is `String` and you invoke with `char[]`. You can do `String passwordEnc = AESencrypt.encrypt(new String(passwordInput))`.

Comment: Could you post the stack trace here?

Comment: @AdrianBer, if you're going to make edits [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1229146) then you should state _clearly_ in the edit summary that you are moving the OPs code from comments to the question. Your edit is unlikely to be approved because it appears as though you are just editing the OPs question to add something _you_ want to add.